# How can I calculate a monthly average including months with no records in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, average, dax

I'm trying to calculate a monthly average number of cases for each investigator. It might be over a quarter, year, or multiple years so it needs to respond to the visual or table context I drop it into. The base table has Case (individual case#), Investigator (person name), Date assigned (not shown), and from that date,month and year columns extracted and a YearMonth categorical column.

[image: mockdata]

I create a caseCount measure as

```
caseCount = COUNT('Table'[Case])
```

[image]

I've tried several different ways to calculate the average over all months (in this case 4). Because Mary has cases in each month, her average is correct (1.75) but Sam's uses a denominator = 3, thus doesn't calculate correctly. (returns 1.3 instead of 1). How can I force the calculation to use the full number of months.

Additional notes:
There may be cases in the table that fall outside the date range I want so I've tried using a

```
Avg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(caseCount), Table[Date] > #10/31/2019#)
```

I've also tried several variations using CALCULATE(DIVIDE(), [Date] > 10/31/2019. Everything seems to exclude those months when an investigator had no investigations assigned. I also tried connecting to a Date table and using the Distinct YearMonth value created there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the evaluation context.
I would define the measure as follow:

```
VAR _casecount = //count number of cases in the selected period, applied on the fact table
VAR _months = COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Calendar'[Month]), ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))) //count number of months in the selected period
RETURN
_casecount/months
```

### Update

I did not consider the scenario of multi-year periods involving May-2019 and May-2020. Then, let's reframe the solution using [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datediff-function-dax):

```
VAR _casecount = //count number of cases in the selected period, applied on the fact table
VAR _firstCalendarDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Calendar'[Date], ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))
VAR _lastCalendarDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Calendar'[Date], ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))
VAR _months = DATEDIFF(_firstCalendarDate, _lastCalendarDate, MONTH)
RETURN
_casecount/months
```

Comment: I tried the suggested function for VAR _months but the COUNTROWS() function only takes a single argument, and thus it is throwing a "too many arguments" error. Should this be in a CALCULATE() wrap with the ALLSELECTED() as a filter in that context?

Comment: I was missing the context modifier. Now fixed.

Comment: I'm still getting a 'too many arguments' error, because COUNTROWS() is receiving >1.

Comment: In addition, if I change to 
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(VALUES('Calendar'[Month])), ALLSELECTED('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Date] > 12/31/2014)
to limit the COUNTROWS() to one argument, AND if I stay within one year, it works. But figuring across years there are only 12 Month values, so it inflates the average. So I used VALUES(YrMon), but it is including all years and YrMon values, instead of filtering to a specific period, thus under-calculating the average.

Comment: I appreciate your initiative in reviewing the answer in order to make it work. I reframed it using DATEDIFF because seems to be more straightforward for your scenario.